# Not declared in scope - friend comparator class for priority_queue C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, priority-queue, friend

First let me condense the relevant code, note the parameter `movies` which produces the error:

```
// ActorGraph.hpp
class ActorGraph
{
protected:
    class Movie; // definition further below
    friend class MovieYearComparator;

    int func(..., priority_queue<Movie, vector<Movie>, MovieYearComparator> &movies);

    class Movie {...};
};
```

In the implementation file we have:

```
// ActorGraph.cpp
class MovieYearComparator
{
public:
    bool operator() (const ActorGraph::Movie a, const ActorGraph::Movie b) const
    {
        // comparison operation
    }
};

ActorGraph::func(..., priority_queue<Movie, vector<Movie>, MovieYearComparator> &movies) 
{...}
```

However, g++ complains that `MovieYearComparator` was **not declared in this scope**, referring to the `func` declaration. I spelled everything correctly and this paradigm is working for other containers in the file, just not the priority queue. Note that `Movie` is a very small class and I therefore chose to pass it by value.

Comment: Try include MovieYearComparator header file

Comment: There is no header file for that class. The implementation details are in `ActorGraph.cpp` which include `ActorGraph.hpp` where `MovieYearComparator` is declared a friend

Comment: Try " class MovieYearComparator " over class ActorGraph

Comment: Tried placing it above `ActorGraph`, but it doesn't compile since the paramters of `operator()` require that type

Comment: @jeanluc You can only use forward-declared types for a pointer or a reference; but now compiler is expect to know `MovieYearComparator` for `func`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you forward-declare a class, you cannot do everything with it, you only have the right to use / store reference or pointer to it, e.g.:

```
struct A;

struct B {
    A *_a; // Ok
    B (A &a) : _a(&a) { } // Ok
};

void f (A a) { } // Oops!
```

The reason is simple: If you do not use a reference or a pointer, the compiler **must** know the size of the `struct` / `class` when using it.

In your case, `priority_queue` needs to use non-reference of the `Comparer`, but since the first time you instantiate the template (in the definition of `ActorGraph`) your `Comparer` (`MovieYearComparator`) is not a complete type, `priority_queue` cannot be instantiated.

You need to **define** the `MovieYearComparator` class before the first instantiation of your `priority_queue`, e.g.:

```
class ActorGraph {
protected:
    class Movie; // definition further below

    class MovieYearComparator
    {
    public:
        // Use reference since your forward-declare Movie
        bool operator() (const ActorGraph::Movie const& a, 
                         const ActorGraph::Movie const& b) const {
            // comparison operation
        }
    };

    int func(..., priority_queue<Movie, vector<Movie>, MovieYearComparator> &movies);

    class Movie {...};
};
```

If you want to keep your header "clean", you could only define the class in the header but implement the `operator()` in the cpp file:

```
class ActorGraph {
protected:
    class Movie; // definition further below

    struct MovieYearComparator {
        bool operator() (const ActorGraph::Movie const& a, 
                         const ActorGraph::Movie const& b) const;
    };

    int func(..., priority_queue<Movie, vector<Movie>, MovieYearComparator> &movies);

    class Movie {...};
};

// .cpp
bool ActorGraph::MovieYearComparator::operator() (const ActorGraph::Movie const& a, 
                                                  const ActorGraph::Movie const& b) const { }
```

Also note that since `MovieYearComparator` is now an inner class of `ActorGraph`, you do not need to make it a friend class.

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense. However, I was trying to keep the header file as clean as possible, and I don't see way to keep `MovieYearComparator` in the implementation file. Is there perhaps a better paradigm I should be using, or should I just suck it up and put it in the header?

Comment: @jeanluc You could only define the class in the header but implement the `operator()` in your cpp file. If you use a `struct`, the code in your header will take about 4 lines (see my edit).